# Joining a monthly table to a delta table to get one record per month

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I wanted to write an efficient SQL query where I would like to join two tables.  Table A (the left table) has a monthly record for each client, and Table B has a delta record for every single time a client made a change to a specific dimension.

For illustrative purpose, the tables could like this:

**Table A – Monthly Table**

```
CLNT_NO ME_DT   STATUS
RAMAN   Jan-19  ACTIVE
RAMAN   Feb-19  ACTIVE
RAMAN   Mar-19  ACTIVE
RAMAN   Apr-19  INACTIVE
RAMAN   May-19  INACTIVE
RAMAN   Jun-19  INACTIVE
RAMAN   Jul-19  INACTIVE
RAMAN   Aug-19  INACTIVE
```

**Table B – Delta Table**

```
CLNT_NO CHNG_DT ADDRESS
RAMAN   Jan-19  TORONTO
RAMAN   Jul-19  MONTREAL
```

**Expected Result**

```
CLNT_NO  ME_DT   STATUS  ADDRESS
RAMAN   Jan-19  ACTIVE  TORONTO
RAMAN   Feb-19  ACTIVE  TORONTO
RAMAN   Mar-19  ACTIVE  TORONTO
RAMAN   Apr-19  INACTIVE    TORONTO
RAMAN   May-19  INACTIVE    TORONTO
RAMAN   Jun-19  INACTIVE    TORONTO
RAMAN   Jul-19  INACTIVE    MONTREAL
RAMAN   Aug-19  INACTIVE    MONTREAL
```

How would I write a join to get the following result in TERADATA SQL

```
Select 

Table A.*

Table B.ADDRESS

From

Table A 

    Left Join Table B

        on Table A.CLNT_NO = Table B.CLNT_NO and HOW TO WRITE DATE JOIN
```

Comment: How are your dates actually stored?  Second question, what is your requirement for comparing the dates between the two tables?

Comment: The requirement is to have a monthly record for every single client and append information from a delta table to have the latest information for that client.  For example, you may be a client for 10 years (120 records) and changed addresses only twice (2 records).  I want the left most table to have 120 records and have the corresponding address record.

Comment: The dates are stored as dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a subquery in the `ON` clause:

```
select a.*, b.address
from a left
     b
     on a.CLNT_NO = b.CLNT_NO and 
        b.ME_DT = (select max(b2.ME_DT)
                   from b b2
                   where b2.CLNT_NO = b.CLNT_NO and b2.me_dt <= a.chng_dt
                  );
```

In most databases, you can express this logic using a correlated subquery.  However, Teradata does not support `TOP` in correlated subqueries, which makes that approach much trickier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but it appears that you basically want your tableA.me_dt to be "between" the tableB.chng_dt?  If so, I'd approach it this way:

```
with tblB as        
(select
    clnt_nm,address,
    chng_dt,
    coalesce(max(chng_dt) over (partition by clnt_nm order by chng_dt desc rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding),date '9999-12-31') as next_dt
from
    tableb
)
select
    tableA.*,tblB.address
from
    tableA
    inner join tblB
        on tableA.clnt_nm = tblB.clnt_nm
        and tableA.me_dt >=  tblB.chng_dt 
        and tableA.me_dt < tblB.next_dt
```

The tblB CSV will basically give you a "begin" date (based on the current row) and an "end" date  (based on the next row).

This is all based on the assumption that your dates are actual dates, not strings as you have them in your post. If they are strings, you'll need to build dates from them.